# On what chapter season 4 of Seven Deadly Sins ends?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

From what chapter should I start reading the manga after the end of season 4 of 7 Deadly Sins?

Answer (score 2):

You can start from Chapter 268 (Volume 33). That is where Meliodas is inside the black cocoon and Ban is inside Purgatory.